# What is the correct way of visually representing more than two variables in one graph?

Tags: data-visualization

Suppose I have data which looks like this

Type of School

```
ENGLISH     156497  11.11%
Non-ENGLISH 1252372 88.89%
```

Gender

```
FEMALE  649465  46.10%
MALE    759405  53.90%
```

School Gender

```
Coeducation 413422  29.78%
FEMALE      436883  31.47%
MALE        537754  38.74%
```

Student Type

```
PRIVATE SCHOOL STUDENT  585947  41.57%
PRIVATE STUDENT         20107   1.43%
PUBLIC SCHOOL STUDENT   803471  57.00%
```

Location

```
RURAL   962959  68.41%
URBAN   444769  31.59%
```

I want to represent all these variables in one graph. Which graph is best suited for it?

Comment: There isn't a "*the* correct way". There may be some good ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bar chart will work fine, but is much better horizontal.

[image]

I've taken small liberties with what was presented, which will be explained and defended.

- The major design choice is **horizontal alignment**, which permits text to run left to right, the easiest reading direction for most readers. The near vertical alignment in the answer by Dave is driven by the need to accommodate several labels and a horizontal axis.
- I use **lower case** text in labels to the extent possible. "English" is best given with an initial capital to follow the usual conventions; otherwise lower case letters take less space and are easier to read (some even report the synaesthetic impression of SHOUTING on reading much upper case).
- Percents are **rounded** to 1 decimal place. That's still 3 significant figures for all but one fraction reported (if any fraction was less than 1%, that might need rethinking).
- I made small **simplifications of wording**.
- The **counts are suppressed**. It's easy to put too much into a graph of this kind. Some people hate numbers on graphs, but to me hybrid graph-tables permit the best of both worlds. Given that, axis ticks and numeric labels can be suppressed too.

Note further

- There is **no stacking of bars**. We don't need it here. A resultant feature is that we don't have to work hard to decode which fractions are bigger (or biggest). It's immediate that males are in a slight majority, all-male schools are the largest single category, and so forth.
- I use a **subdued colour**. Solid blocks of heavy colour are hard on the eye and brain. I don't use several colours. The text labels show what is what: we don't need a raid on the elementary school paintbox. If printing colour were a constraint, light grey bars with black outline are essentially always possible.
- Note that there is no **legend**, a common small evil in displays of this kind, which only obliges the conscientious reader to go back and forth to decode the display (and tempts the less conscientious reader not to engage with the display in any serious sense). Here, and often, we can lose the legend in favour of text labels by each bar.
- There is a presumption that the researcher would add a **figure caption** or other text explaining place, time, data collection and definition details of importance, and so forth. The units could be emphasised as percent in the caption. Showing percent on the graph too would be perfectly defensible, and many would prefer it.
- The **outer text labels are perhaps superfluous**. For example, given `male` and `female` as labels, `gender` adds nothing. Similarly, `rural` and `urban` don't need the gloss `location`.  In context, which I don't know  here, the distinction between `English` and `non-English` might also be clear to the reader. In a paper or presentation, there should always be explanations somewhere, unless categories are presumed self-evident. Equally, a graph should be self-contained as far as practicable and not rely on the reader recalling details that may have been given once and quickly, or are in tables or supplementary material not yet accessed.

A horizontal (Cleveland) dot chart would perform as well. In practice, very many audiences, including many lay groups, are familiar and comfortable with bar charts, and much less familiar with dot charts, which often gives the bar chart design a major edge.

For the record, I used Stata. Non-Stata users need not care, but they might be interested in seeing whether their own favourite software requires less or more code.

```
clear 
input id str14 what str15 which count percent 
1 "type of school" "English"     156497  11.11
1 "type of school" "non-English" 1252372 88.89
2 "gender" "female"  649465  46.10
2 "gender" "male"    759405  53.90
3 "school" "coeducation" 413422  29.78
3 "school" "female"      436883  31.47
3 "school" "male"        537754  38.74
4 "student type" "private school"  585947  41.57
4 "student type" "private student"         20107   1.43
4 "student type" "public school"   803471  57.00
5 "location" "rural"   962959  68.41
5 "location" "urban"   444769  31.59
end 

labmask id, values(what)
graph hbar (asis) percent, over(which, gap(*0.5)) over(id) nofill bar(1, bfcolor(green*0.1)) blabel(total, format(%2.1f)) yla(none) ysc(r(0 100)) scheme(s1color)
```

Comment: Nice answer Nick. I tend not to like plots that list the numbers being plotted, but your comment about the best of both worlds has given me something to think about. I find your preference for lower-case text interesting too.

Comment: @mark999 Thanks! A typical scatter plot, say, would indeed be overloaded with numbers alongside too. But what is the purpose of a bar chart like this? Arguably, it is mainly as a visual table. I think the art with the number text is to make it legible, but not **too** large. Note that a common option of putting the numbers inside the bars would not work well here.

Comment: Do you say that numbers inside the bars would not work well here just because the 1.4 wouldn't fit, or is there another reason? I seem to remember that one objection that some people (possibly Frank Harrell?) have to "dynamite plots" is that the error bars can create an optical illusion, causing the viewer to misjudge the relative heights or lengths of the main bars. I wonder if the numbers could have a similar effect.

Comment: Many of us are trained to think that Figures are figures and Tables are tables, and ne'er the twain shall meet. But there is a serious argument that this distinction is just a 500-year-long side-effect of the invention of printing: printers print Tables but Figures required the work of different technicians. Before printing, manuscript  writers put graphics where they wanted and used semi-graphic elements too (think Leonardo).  Now we can hybridise too.

Comment: It's mostly the 1.4. I dislike a mix of styles, some numbers inside bars, some not. I too have often objected to dynamite or detonator plots, but not because of latent visual illusions. They are not informative enough, and put the emphasis on what is usually the wrong detail (size relative to zero).

Answer (score 0):

[image: comparison graph]

I like the idea of a bar graph to show each value, but to each his own